# Bootstrap columns with wrapping

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need a layout like this:
[image]

1. responsive design (based on bootstrap 3)
2. col-sm-7 (purple) has fixed height, but optional
3. col-sm-5 (blue) has variable height(not dynamic), optional
4. bottom text (green) should wrap purple
   and blue blocks and take full width (col-sm-12)
5. Blocks can has additional classed depends on presence of another blocks
6. In mobile view they should be staked:

[image]

Is it possible to implement this behavior by bootstrap markup & css? How?

Comment: inside geen block -- text. Impossible to solve it by merging of two blocks. Absolute position also not so good with responsive design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a `.pull-left` class to the blue and purple containers.

Scenario 1: http://jsfiddle.net/xawvez5o/

Scenario 2: http://jsfiddle.net/xawvez5o/1/

Scenario 3: http://jsfiddle.net/xawvez5o/2/

Scenario 4: http://jsfiddle.net/xawvez5o/3/